# how to fit complex mysql query into zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

i am unable to fit my query into zf2 query, i can fit simple join query but i can not write for more complex sub queries.
please help me to do this.

```
SELECT `created_date` FROM `salesmodule_discussed_topic` dt WHERE dt.`meeting_id` IN( 
SELECT ma.`meeting_id` FROM `salesmodule_meeting_agent` ma WHERE ma.`agent_id`=30547
)



public function getLastmeetingdate() {
        $select = new Select();
        $select->from(array('dt' => 'salesmodule_discussed_topic'));
        $select->columns(array('created_date'));
        $select->where(array('ma.`agent_id` => 30547));
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        return $resultSet->buffer();
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public function fetchAllSubQuery($id = '') {
    $columns = array("*");
    $where = "main_booking_id IN (SELECT 
            b1.`main_booking_id` 
            FROM
            `booking_sector` b1 
            WHERE b1.`connected_booking_id` = '$id' OR b1.`main_booking_id` = '$id') ";
     $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($where,$columns) {
            $select->where($where);
            $select->columns($columns);
        });
    $resultSet->buffer();
    // $resultSet->next();
    return $resultSet;
}
```

Comment: `WHERE b1.connected_booking_id = '$id'` MySql Injection

Answer (score 2):

The previous example is bad because has an `sql injections`. You need make a subquery using `Select`.

```
public function getLastmeetingdate() {
    $subQuery = new Select();
    $subQuery->from(array('ma' => 'salesmodule_meeting_agent'));
    $subQuery->columns(array('meeting_id'));
    $subQuery->where(array('ma.agent_id' => 30547));

    $select = new Select();
    $select->from(array('dt' => 'salesmodule_discussed_topic'));
    $select->columns(array('created_date'));
    $select->where->in('dt.meeting_id', $subQuery);

    return $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
}
```